# Vue component does not render

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get a vue component to work from a separate file called AppButton.js. This simple learning component should render a button with some css and disables the click when one hovers over the button.  Instead, this code just displays text. I cannot figure out what is missing in my code and I would appreciate if someone can take a look.

Here is the content from **AppButton.js**:

```
export default {
    template: '<button class="bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 border rounded px-5 py-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed"  v-bind:disabled="processing"><slot /></button>',
    data() {
        return {
            processing: true
        }
    }
}
```

The AppButton.js is in the same directory as my index.html. Here is the content of the **index.html**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-full">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>


<body class="h-full grid place-items-center">
  <div id="app">
    <app-button>Scura</app-button>
  </div>
  <script type="module">
    import AppButton from "AppButton.js"
    let app = {
      components: {
        'app-button': AppButton
      }
    };
    Vue.createApp(app).mount('#app');
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried loading vue.js devtools extension in my Chrome to debug this problem further but for some reason the vue.js devtools extension does not show in my [devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfLmP.jpg)

This is the error I am getting in Chrome Console: Access to script at

```
'file:///C:/Users/scura/Documents/LearnHtmlCss/js/components/AppButton.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
index.html:18          GET file:///C:/Users/scura/Documents/LearnHtmlCss/js/components/AppButton.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Only non related to the vue component: (index):62 cdn.tailwindcss.com should not be used in production. To use Tailwind CSS in production, install it as a PostCSS plugin or use the Tailwind CLI: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: Now I am getting a "better" error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "AppButton.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: where is "AppButton.js"? give relative path and try again

Comment: I gave a relative path correctly and I am getting a new error message in the console. I am running this vue component on windows if that matters.
Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/scura/Documents/LearnHtmlCss/js/components/AppButton.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
index.html:18          GET file:///C:/Users/scura/Documents/LearnHtmlCss/js/components/AppButton.js net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: After fixing the import path, I [cannot reproduce the other issue you mentioned](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-wpbxsk?file=index.html,AppButton.js).

Comment: Thank you so much @tony19 I believe it happens while I work with files from the filesystem in Chrome and not on a server. My understanding is that the issue after fixing the import path has nothing to do with vue but with chrome and the file system instead.